# Pass OAUTH access token from mobile client to server

Tags: php, security, rest, mobile, oauth-2.0

I have enabled Oauth protocol in PHP for my REST APIs for multiple mobile apps.

Once I pass access token from server to client, client can store it anywhere for further server calls. How secure these token values are since anybody can easily hack token or any stored values on client side.

Also, what is best approach to make REST calls from client to server with access token? Should it be always POST or it is possible to secure access token even with GET? I am just curious to know what are best possible ways to avoid security attacks.

Answer (score 0):

OAut is itself secure, if still you are worried you can do following.
Use SSL and make its a Secure Socket.
Also you can encrypt token which will be decrypted on client side.

Server and client needs to follow same encryption and decryption algorithm.

I suppose this will lessen your nightmare.